# HTML select dropdown list items based on an xml

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, dynamic

Hi I need to create a select dropdown list based on an xml dynamically.

lets say I have the ff. xml, **xmlSelSROption**:

```
<PMLookupResponse>
        <Row LookupID="3" LookupType="CTR" LookupName="Good" LookupOrder="1" LookupDescription="Checklist status is pass." LookupStatus="1"/>
        <Row LookupID="4" LookupType="CTR" LookupName="Fair" LookupOrder="2" LookupDescription="Checklist status is fail." LookupStatus="1"/>
        <Row LookupID="5" LookupType="CTR" LookupName="Needs Repair" LookupOrder="3" LookupDescription="Checklist status is not applicable." LookupStatus="1"/>
        <Row LookupID="6" LookupType="CTR" LookupName="Not Inspected" LookupOrder="4" LookupDescription="Checklist status is complete." LookupStatus="1"/>
        <Row LookupID="7" LookupType="CTR" LookupName="N/A" LookupOrder="5" LookupDescription="Checklist status is not complete." LookupStatus="1"/>
        <Row LookupID="0" LookupName="None"/>
</PMLookupResponse>
```

This is built on javascript. Now on the html part of my page, I have a dropdown list **selOptionSR**

```
<select id="selOptionSR"></select>
```

Now there are some parts of the page wherein the xml appends rows, or removes childrows.

Is it possible that my dropdown list gets updated based on the xml? I want the options to be the attribute **LookupName**. and the value is their **LookupID**. If you know how using javascript. Please tell me. Thank you.

Comment: How?? I dont really know how to implement this in javascript. (newbie)

Comment: Dupe - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14965790/using-jquery-ajax-to-populate-a-drop-down-menu-with-xml-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an event to trigger the drop down list box upon updation of the xml contents, then write a event handler for the dropdown list box to get update based on the latest xml content .

```
$('#xml').on('change',function (){
      $('#list').empty();
     $(this).find('Row').each(function() {  //loop through complete rows
          att= $(this).attr('LookupName');  //extract attribute
          val= $(this).attr('LookupID');    //extract value

          $('#list').append('<option value'+ val+'>'+att +'</option>'); 
     });
 });
```

*Above code is just an prototype based on the prerequisites provided by author*

Happy Coding :)